# [Python]How to order the value of json array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I got a json array like this

```
[{'n0': 16}, {'n2': 6}, {'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n5': 11}, {'n6': 2}, {'n7': 6}]
```

How can i order this one depends on the value of nX?

Comment: it's not working, how should i do? @KenjiNoguchi

Comment: `print(sorted(data, key=lambda e: list(e.values())[0]))`  the output is `[{'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n6': 2}, {'n2': 6}, {'n7': 6}, {'n5': 11}, {'n0': 16}]`

Comment: sorted(d, key=lambda x:list(x.items())[0][0][1])

Comment: depending on your context, this might be useful as well: `[(k,v) for di in d for (k,v) in sorted(di.items(), key=lambda x:x[0][1])]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
   def getkey(item):
      return int(item.keys()[0][1:])

    def compare(a,b):
      k1,k2=getkey(a),getkey(b)
      if k1 == k2 :
        return 0
      return -1 if k1 <k2 else 1

    print l 

    l.sort(compare)
```

.. and the list is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

use python [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function with key

```
lst = [{'n0': 16}, {'n2': 6}, {'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n5': 11}, {'n6': 2}, {'n7': 6}]
new_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x:x.values()[0])
# [{'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n6': 2}, {'n2': 6}, {'n7': 6}, {'n5': 11}, {'n0': 16}]
```

if you want to sort the list in place without creating new list, use list `sort` method

```
lst = [{'n0': 16}, {'n2': 6}, {'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n5': 11}, {'n6': 2}, {'n7': 6}]
lst.sort(key=lambda x:x.values()[0])
# [{'n3': 1}, {'n4': 1}, {'n6': 2}, {'n2': 6}, {'n7': 6}, {'n5': 11}, {'n0': 16}]
```